# «Утром на трассе под Татарстаном...»

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Где найти правила об употреблении предлогов места в русском языке? Какое правило не учёл автор фразы?

Answer (score 1):

Шикарррно. Урожай на полях Ньюйоркщины и Вашингтонщины...

Вот что нашлось:

[Особенности использований предлогов «с» и «из», «в» и «на», «по» и «о»](https://www.calc.ru/Osobennosti-Upravleniya-I-Ispolzovaniya-Predlogov-V-Slovosoc.html)

Предлог «под» используется с винительным и творительным падежами. В качестве примеров с творительным - "нашим" приведены... [города](https://www.lingq.com/ru/lesson/4-predlog-pod-319977/). Можно любой населённый пункт, но составителям правил в голову не приходит как-то особо оговаривать страны, государства... Это [русский как иностранный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Ой-ё, нашла! И "под", и страна, и творительный:

[Что находится под Россией с обратной стороны Земли?](https://pikabu.ru/story/chto_nakhoditsya_pod_rossiey_s_obratnoy_storonyi_zemli_6511740)

А ещё вот так можно:

[Полтавская битва на долгие годы определила политическое будущее Украины. Волынь и Галичина остались под Польшей, Киев и Левобережье – под Россией, юг Украины – под Турцией.](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=969&tbm=bks&ei=fYPGXPSMBumErwTXi6u4BQ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9&gs_l=psy-ab.12...22869.22869.0.25416.1.1.0.0.0.0.79.79.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.qem4tJE-qUo)

Типичное не то. Не наш случай. Трассы остались недорассмотрены...

Не бывает трасс под республиками, хошь бы оне и субъект, - ни утром, ни вечером, ни во веки веков, аминь.

Зато есть стихи психа, тута:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Будем искать... Последний пример, если понимать буквально этого спощного поэта, — про взгляд не на глобус, а из глобуса.